# Django ImageField Uploaded to Different Path than Reported by url property?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, imagefield

I'd like to allow users to upload profile pictures and then to display them.

Here's my **model.py**:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, ImageField, Model

class Eater(Model):
    name  = CharField(max_length = 30)
    image = ImageField(upload_to = 'images/eaters/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Here's my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf             import settings  # settings is an object, not a module, so you can't import from it. :(
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls             import path
from .views                  import EaterView, IndexView, post, sudo

app_name    = 'socialfeedia'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',      IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # Static returns a list of path, not a path itself.
```

This is at the end of my **settings.py**:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.joinpath('media/')
```

Here's a line out of my **index.html**:

```
<img class="post-profile-picture" src="{{ post.eater.image.url }}" alt="?"/>
```

I successfully uploaded a file into this field - it got stored at:

```
mysite/media/images/eaters/test_picture_64.jpg
```

The image loads successfully if I visit it here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/socialfeedia/media/images/eaters/test_picture_64.jpg
```

However, the `img` that shows up in my generated file is this:

```
<img class="post-profile-picture" src="/media/images/eaters/test_picture_64.jpg" alt="?">
```

This file doesn't resolve - I just see a `?` (the `alt`) instead. Should I be using something else to get the correct path to the file instead? Something like this maybe?

```
{% media post.eater.name %}
```

(Except no such thing as `media` exists as far as I can tell...)

It should be including `socialfeedia/` (the app name) at the start of the url but it isn't... it doesn't seem very much like what I've seen of Django so far to expect me to manually hardcode that in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is to move

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # Static returns a list of path, not a path itself.
```

from `urls.py` file of your app `socialfeedia` to the global `urls.py` file under the project package and don't forget to set the **namespace** `socialfeedia` in the corresponding urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path, include

from django.contrib import admin

[..]

urlpatterns = [

    [..]

    path('socialfeedia/', include('socialfeedia.urls', namespace='socialfeedia')),  # HERE

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  # Admin Area
]


# DEBUG = True
if settings.DEBUG:

    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right. Now that I'm looking back, I can see that all the examples I saw of people using `static()` were in `urls.py` files mentioning `admin/`, so they would have been in the project/site/main `urls.py` file, not the app's `urls.py` file. I'll be sure to look out for this kind of thing in the future working with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `{% get_media_prefix %}` at the beginning of `src` worked for me but I'm pretty sure it's not the right solution.

```
<img class="post-profile-picture" src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ post.eater.image.url }}" alt="?"/>
```

Comment: This may have worked - I didn't try. The other answer worked and feels like the "right" way to do it.